# Module-local public methods

Tags: java, module

I have a module (Jigsaw) named `app.gui` with following package hierarchy:

- app.gui

inside app.gui:

- base (GuiElement.java)
- control (SampleControl.java)
- layout (SampleControlPane.java)

The module contains custom JavaFX nodes.

***THE PROBLEM***

I want to:

- keep the package structure
- access the method mentioned in `SampleControlPane.java` source code comment (below)
- have the method `getRootNode()` encapsulated, so it will be accessible only in the current module

How can I do this? If I made `getRootNode()` public it will be accessible outside the module.

Source code below:

[GuiElement] is parent of all custom nodes

```
public abstract class GuiElement<T extends Region> {

    private final T rootNode;

    public GuiElement(T rootNode) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(rootNode, "rootNode must not be null");
        this.rootNode = rootNode;
    }

    //Package &S ubclasses API

    protected final T getRootNode() {
        return rootNode;
    }

}
```

[SampleControl] is a custom control.

```
public final class SampleControl extends GuiElement<HBox> {
    
    public SampleControl() {
        super(new HBox());
        getRootNode().getChildren().add(new Button("My Button"));
    }
    
}
```

[SampleControlPane] is a layout container (for multiple `SampleControl`)

```
public final class SampleControlPane extends GuiElement<VBox> {

    public SampleControlPane(SampleControl... controls) {
        super(new VBox());
        for (SampleControl c : controls) {
            //can't access c.getRootNode() here
        }
    }

}
```